# Can I use static test methods?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying MS Test. Visual Studio doesn't find any tests from the following code unless I remove the `static` keyword.

```
[TestClass]
public static class TestMain2
{

    [TestMethod]
    public static void TestMergeWildcard()
    {
         ....
    }
}
```

I guess MS Test doesn't support static test methods.

Is there a documentation stating this limitation or did I only miss some attribute or need to turn on an option?

I used "MS Test static test methods" in Google search, but all results are about testing static methods..

Comment: This is not limitation - it is by design. Class with test methods provide possibility to encapsulate context of tests based on test framework you are using.

Comment: Don't forget that you are writing test and application in object orienting programming language ;)

Comment: @Fabio Does the design try to have better concurrency support? If it allows static classes and methods, users can store data on class fields, and may affect concurrency..

Comment: Not necessary. Some frameworks create new instance of class for every test method.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to make both the class and method static?
Normally you mark them as [TestClass] and [TestMethod] and run the tests.

Maybe this helps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing

Comment: Because my test methods are self-contained, don't reference instance fields, I don't need them to be static.